# Angular velocity of the minute hand

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

The exercise is to calculate the angular velocity (in radians per hour) of the rotation of:

1. the hour hand, and
2. the minute hand (of the clock).

Neither of my answers coincides with the answers in the book:

1. (after corrections) The hour hand goes $30$° in an hour, so the answer I get is $\color{red}{\pi \over 6}$ rad/hour, but the book has $\color{blue}{2\pi}$ rad/hour.
2. (after corrections) The minute hand goes $360$° in an hour, so the answer I get is $\color{red}{2\pi}$ rad/hour, but the book has $\color{blue}{\pi \over 30}$ rad/hour.

Thank you for all your comments so far. I guess the question is now: are the red ones right or the blue ones? I no longer know what's going on with this textbook.

Comment: What? You're both wrong. The *minute* hand goes $360^\circ$ in an hour. The hour hand just does $1/12$th of a turn in an hour.

Comment: The hour hand goes $360^{\circ}$ an hour? No!! It's only $30^{\circ}$, right? The minute hand makes one rotation in an hour, not 60. Its the seconds hand that makes 60 rotations in an hour!! Drop that book, it seems dangerous ;)

Comment: The "book" answer says the minute hand moves more slowly than the hour hand, so it's clearly wrong.  However I might expect "velocity", a signed quantity, to be negative for both hour and minute hands, since the movement is "clockwise" and math typically orients the angular rotation as positive in a counterclockwise direction.

Comment: I'm sorry about the 360. Let me re-check my notes, re-calculate and see if the problem disappears. Thank you for that.

Comment: Your answers are correct.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks. I'm now seriously considering tpb261's suggestion.

Comment: @Readingtao Haha, problems are always good. Solutions, are secondary. So, don't drop the book :D